# why does appending a substituted List, modify the orginal list too in python?

Tags: python, list, append, substitution

I want to manipulate a List in python while keeping the original List untouched.
So I've substituted the Original List into a new defined variable as below :

```
Original_List = [1,5]
Substituted_List = Orginal_List
```

But I've noticed doing `Substituted_List.append()` also modify the Original_List too:

```
Substituted_List.append(3)
print("Original list is: %s" %Original_List)
print("Substituted list is: %s" %Substituted_List)
```

The output is:

```
Original list is: [1,5,3]
Substituted list is: [1,5,3]
```

While the Original list is supposed to be: `[1,5]`

Comment: Read Ned Batcheler's [Facts and myths about Python names and variables](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: You also have typo mistake, u declared `Original_List` and second line you refered `Orginal_List`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are referencing the same object:

```
>>> Original_List = [1,5]
>>> Substituted_List = Original_List
>>> 
>>> id(Original_List)
140473860198344
>>> id(Substituted_List)
140473860198344
>>>
```

you need to use:

```
Substituted_List = Original_List[:]
```

or you can use:

```
import copy
Substituted_List = copy.copy(Original_List)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are copying the `reference`

```
Substituted_List = Original_List
```

To make a copy instead use a `slice` operation :

```
Substituted_List = Original_List[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept is that in Python each and every variable is an object which points to your data in memory. When a list is substituted to another variable(object), then the other variable also references to the old memory point which the original variable has pointed to. If you do not want that the substituted list-variable gets changed then use list() function.
ex:-

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list2 = list(list1)
>>> print(list1, list2)
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
>>> list1[2]=4
>>> print(list1, list2)
[1, 2, 4] [1, 2, 3]
```